# Tradition for Choosing What to Call a Secular Holiday on a Hebrew Calendar

Tags: halacha, names, non-jewish-holidays

I received a solicitation for a donation from a well-known and rather large centrist Orthodox Yeshiva/Mesifta/Kollel in Brooklyn. The organization included in the mailing a weekly pocket diary as a gift. I noticed that some American holidays were noted by name such as  Labor Day, Thanksgiving, Independence Day; others, such as MLK Day, Lincoln's Birthday, and January 1st/New Year's were noted by the designation "Secular Holiday."  It seems in addition to January 1st/New Years Day, all of the holiday's named for someone (Lincoln, Washington, not sure Columbus) or were Christian in nature (Easter, Christmas, All Soul's Day, Etc, were listed either as "Secular Holiday" or not at all.

What is the halakhic reasoning/sources  guiding the decision of naming/printing  the American holidays  by their actual name or for substituting "Secular Holiday" in their place? Where did this tradition begin and how long has it existed?

Comment: I also got a few calendars from various orgs. but I never paid attention to this nuance. It seems that generally, Christmas is not referred to at all. Seems to be common that relig. Jews don't mention it. New Years? Not sure - perhaps because of the name itself, as it is not the Jewish New Year? As for the other days such as Wash. B'Day, etc. you got me on that one. First I've heard of it. Offhand, I'm unaware that there is any halachic requirement that says that we cannot put down Christmas on a calendar. AFAIK, a printed paper calendar that just shows dates has no *kedusha* whatsoever.